# Make React Native take over my website link and open in my React native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to know how to make react native handle all clicks/ calls to my website link.
E.g. Any time I click or open my website address, say `mysite.com/post/:postId`, there should be a pop up that asks if I want to open the link with my app or browser.

I have been able to achieve this with my custom link `myapp://myapp/post/:id` using `Linking` api and `react-navigation` and works perfectly, but I would like to achieve this with a normal website url.

Comment: Please take a look Firebase Dynamic Links 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: also on Branch.io

Comment: This is called deep linking. Here's a tutorial that explains how to set it up for ios: https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

Comment: I want exactly same functionality. Can you tell me how you achieve this functionality @kenshinman

Comment: Hello, @KishanBharda I used react-navigation to implement this.

Comment: Can it done with only react-navigation? or we have to use firebase dynamic link with it ? Have you any example ? Thanks.